# Calculating current month range using Datedif

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm currently using the below formula to find which month I'm in out of the designated range - 1 of 13.

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(2019,1,1),$A$1,"M")+1&" of 13"
```

$A$1 is referencing a specific date of 12/1/18. Excel is throwing a #NUM error because I'm guessing the new date of 1/1/2019 is in a different year? I'm not sure how to correct this? It will work fine once I update the specific date to January 2019, but I need it to show 0 of 13 until then.

Help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF(DATE(2019,1,1),$A$1,"M")+1,0)&" of 13"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEDIF` function operates with the following parameters

```
=DATEDIF (start_date, end_date, unit)
```

The `end_date` needs to be greater than or equal to the `start_date`. You can ensure this by using `MAX` and `MIN`.

```
=DATEDIF(MIN(DATE(2019,1,1),$A$1),MAX(MIN(DATE(2019,1,1),$A$1)),"M")+1&" of 13"
```